# Can we keep the ports opened for a websphere application server running inside a container even if the server is stopped?

Tags: docker, tcp, containers, websphere, websphere-9

I am trying to remote access(using RAD) a websphere application server which is running inside a container . I am able to see in RAD that the server is started after creating a remote profile for the server in my local . But I can't start the server once its down . After some investigation I realized its because once the application server is stopped from remote machine , my local machine cant talk to that container anymore (although the container is still up and running). Is it possible to persist the connection even thought the app server is down but the container is still up and running ?

Comment: Did you try `docker run --restart always`?

Comment: No I did not but just to be clear , containers are always running its just the application server is brought down and then I cannot start it from the RAD(container WAS instance at local) . Not sure what would this command do . Can you please explain

Comment: Ok so after understanding docker run --restart always . I think this is when you want to automatically restart your docker containers . But in my case container is always running